# What is the longitude and latitude of Tokyo, Japan

Tags: latitude-longitude

Please help me I need to know for a project

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about geography trivia: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3416/is-geography-trivia-on-topic

Comment: However, this does prompt (at least for me) the question of what does it mean to specify the lat/lon of a city (or any place) that is not a point?

Answer (score 1):

Lat 35.6801, Lon 139.7685. Please do your research before asking question.